# Importing "firebase/app" Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hi I'm starting with webpack and firebase. Everytime when I do :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
```

This is the error:
[image]

File structure:
[image]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WElcome</title>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dark",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.17.0"
  }
}
```

I already tried to do it all over again but I installed firebase with npm i firebase in this folder, and always gives me the same error. What I'm missing ?

Comment: looks like 9.17.0 is bugged , same app worked with 9.16 , not working anymore since i tested with 9.17.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is very complicated issue it maybe `firebase v- 9.17.0` is bugged, or it is The module you're trying to import has a different casing or `webpack.config.js`. Issue
but for now you can run.

```
    npm un firebase
    npm i firebase@9.16.0
```

After some more consideration I find 2 more solutions :
1 you can import using /compact

```js
import 'firebase/compat/analytics';

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

import 'firebase/compat/auth';

import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Or, use the latest version :

```
Version `9.17.1 - February 3, 2023`
```

Moved `exports.default fields` to always be the last field. This fixes a bug introduced in `9.17.0` that prevented some bundlers and frameworks from building. For these build failures, the error text is: "Default condition should be last one".

Ref : https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Answer (score 0):

According to firebase documents: Update imports to v9 compat. In order to keep your code functioning after updating your dependency from v8 to v9 beta, change your import statements to use the “compat” version of each import. For example:

Before: version 8

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/storage";
```

After: version 9 compat // v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import "firebase/compat/database";
import "firebase/compat/storage";
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72186925

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: import
firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
firebase": "^10.7.2,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).